# What's the word for contents that are left in glass after a drink is finished?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word the contents that are left in the glass after a drink is finished?

eg:

> 'He drained his glass to the ______'

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this question. I immediately thought of the current answer myself, and I can't see how there could be confusion over what was being looked for. I see no reason why this needed to be closed.

Comment: @Jason it isnt an exemplary question in that it doesn't fulfill SWR requirements.

Comment: @marcellothearcane The requirements are a guideline that should lead to understanding, if followed. In most cases they work well for that purpose and they are needed. Here, there is no problem with understanding and nothing further is needed. The meaning of the question is apparent as it's written.

Answer (score 9):

[Dregs](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dregs) - The dregs of a liquid are the last drops left at the bottom of a container, together with any solid bits that have sunk to the bottom.

As noted this isn't limited to the contents of a glass (i.e. the container could be a bottle or cup, etc.)